# OData - How to convert PageResult<T> to IHttpActionResult

Tags: c#, odata

I have a `PageResult<T> GetXXX(...)` method on my Controller, in which I am fetching data and returning it as `PageResult<T>`, now when there is any error or there is no content, I want to return out the response as `HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError` and `HttpStatusCode.NoContent`

If I keep the return type of my method as `IHttpActionResult` then I get an error saying:

> 'Cannot create an EDM model as the action 'GetXXX' on controller 'YYY'
>   has a return type 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult' that does not
>   implement IEnumerable'

If i dont use PageResult and simply return all my data then I dont get errors.

I have to use `PageResult<T>` because I am managing my own paging.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetXXX(...)
{
     PageResult<XXX> finalResult = new PageResult<XXX>(mydata, new Uri(...), Count);
     return Ok<IEnumerable<XXX>>(finalResult.Items);
}
```

Comment: you should return empty data, and have validation on client side

Comment: okay, but i still need to handle internal server error, coz at the moment it is printing stacktrace

Comment: your server should have validation for the case in which there are no current elements for the page

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking this,

```
  PageResult<T> yourPageResult = new PageResult<T>(...);
  return Ok(yourPageResult)
```

Comment: it does not work, neither does Ok(yourPageResult.Items)

Comment: updated the question with my code, it is pretty much the same as you have posted